# Installing Alpine Linux fails to scan the mirror list with "403 Forbidden"

Tags: alpine-linux

I'm trying to install Alpine Linux running on QEMU and I've got the following errors (I marked the error messages with `<===`):

```
localhost:~# setup-alpine
Available keyboard layouts:
...
Which timezone are you in? ('?' for list) [UTC]
 * Starting busybox acpid ...
 [ ok ]
 * Starting busybox crond ...
 [ ok ]
HTTP/FTP proxy URL? (e.g. 'http://proxy:8080', or 'none') [none] http://192.0.2.1:8080
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden                     <===
r) Add random from the above list
f) Detect and add fastest mirror from above list
e) Edit /etc/apk/repositories with text editor

Enter mirror number (1-0) or URL to add (or r/f/e/done) [f]: f
Finding fastest mirror...
Warning! No mirror found                                                <===
r) Add random from the above list
f) Detect and add fastest mirror from above list
e) Edit /etc/apk/repositories with text editor

Enter mirror number (1-0) or URL to add (or r/f/e/done) [f]: r
/sbin/setup-apkrepos: line 30: divide by zero                           <===
Which SSH server? ('openssh', 'dropbear' or 'none') [openssh]
 * service sshd added to runlevel default
 * Caching service dependencies ...
 [ ok ]
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
 * Starting sshd ...
 [ ok ]
Available disks are:
  sda   (107.4 GB ATA      QEMU HARDDISK   )
Which disk(s) would you like to use? (or '?' for help or 'none') [none] sda
The following disk is selected:
  sda   (107.4 GB ATA      QEMU HARDDISK   )
How would you like to use it? ('sys', 'data', 'lvm' or '?' for help) [?] sys
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:                                       <===
  sfdisk (missing):                                                     <===
    required by: world[sfdisk]                                          <===
  syslinux (missing):                                                   <===
    required by: world[syslinux]                                        <===
localhost:~#
```

After seeing `/sbin/setup-apkrepos:30` (which corresponds to [here](https://git.alpinelinux.org/alpine-conf/tree/setup-apkrepos.in?h=2.11-stable#n24)) and `grep -rn wget /sbin/`, I found out that the proxy server in my office (`http://192.0.2.1:8080`) returns `403 Forbidden` [when the mirror list is requested](https://git.alpinelinux.org/alpine-conf/tree/setup-apkrepos.in?id=8dc1157#n169):

```
localhost:~# export http_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:8080; export https_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:8080; export ftp_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:8080
localhost:~# wget https://mirrors.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.txt
Connecting to 192.0.2.1:8080 (192.0.2.1:8080)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
localhost:~#
```

Though I'm not an administrator of the proxy server, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Perhaps you should check the proxy server's logs for the rejection reason?

Comment: @grawity Exactly, but I'm not the administrator of the proxy server and I **have to** use the proxy. The expression "my proxy server" was misleading, sorry. I've updated the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass `wget` by setting the the environment variable `MIRRORS` to the contents of https://mirrors.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.txt, e.g.:

```sh
export MIRRORS='http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
http://uk.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/'
```

```
localhost:~# export MIRRORS='http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
> http://uk.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
> http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/'
localhost:~# setup-alpine
...
HTTP/FTP proxy URL? (e.g. 'http://proxy:8080', or 'none') [none] http://192.0.2.1:8080
                                                                        <=== OK
Available mirrors:
1) dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org
2) uk.alpinelinux.org
3) dl-2.alpinelinux.org

r) Add random from the above list
f) Detect and add fastest mirror from above list
e) Edit /etc/apk/repositories with text editor

Enter mirror number (1-3) or URL to add (or r/f/e/done) [f]: f
Finding fastest mirror...
0.17 http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/                              <=== OK
0.55 http://uk.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
0.52 http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/
Added mirror dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org
Updating repository indexes... done.
Which SSH server? ('openssh', 'dropbear' or 'none') [openssh]
 * rc-update: sshd already installed in runlevel `default'; skipping
 * WARNING: sshd has already been started
Available disks are:
  sda  (107.4 GB ATA      QEMU HARDDISK   )
Which disk(s) would you like to use? (or '?' for help or 'none') [none] sda
The following disk is selected:
  sda  (107.4 GB ATA      QEMU HARDDISK   )
How would you like to use it? ('sys', 'data', 'lvm' or '?' for help) [?] sys
WARNING: The following disk(s) will be erased:                          <=== OK
  sda  (107.4 GB ATA      QEMU HARDDISK   )
WARNING: Erase the above disk(s) and continue? [y/N]: y
Creating file systems...
Installing system on /dev/sda3:
/mnt/boot is device /dev/sda1
100% ████████████████████████████████████████████==> initramfs: creating /boot/initramfs-virt
/boot is device /dev/sda1

Installation is complete. Please reboot.
localhost:~#
```

This solution is inferred from [the source](https://git.alpinelinux.org/alpine-conf/tree/setup-apkrepos.in?id=8dc1157#n168).